# Check if element exists on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to check whether a certain element exists on another page (under the same domain) without pulling it into the current page using jQuery? I want to get the ID of an element on a different page. For example, there's index.html and index2.html. Now there's a div.foo on index2.html and I want to get its id. I would then pull that element into index.html if I think it's one that I'm looking for.

As it stands, I can use jquery .load() but as far as I understand it, it pulls the elements into index.html first. I think that would be a little redundant incase the div in question doesn't satisfy the requirements I need before I pull it into the current page.

So is there a way to check elements on a different page without pulling it into the page first? This is mainly academic though as I'm ready to use .load() when it comes down to it. I just don't like to do something unecessary when I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way that you can check a html file's contents with client-side scripting without getting it first. cause javascript works in the client's computer, who has no idea what index2.html might have.

**BUT** if that computer ever visited index2.html before, you can put that elements name on cookie and check it in index.html without loading it first.

Comment: Hmm, so I guess I don't have a choice but to use .load(). I just thought that since it's able to get the element, it would be possible to simply read it. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

No , you can't. You should make ajax call like .ajax, .load, .get to read the content of index2.html.